What's the meaning of this change in the Conjugate Gradient algorithm?
The Wikipedia article on the Conjugate gradient method describes the algorithm as:
\begin{aligned}&\mathbf {r} _{0}:=\mathbf {b} -\mathbf {Ax} _{0}\\&{\hbox{if }}\mathbf {r} _{0}{\text{ is sufficiently small, then return }}\mathbf {x} _{0}{\text{ as the result}}\\&\mathbf {p} _{0}:=\mathbf {r} _{0}\\&k:=0\\&{\text{repeat}}\\&\qquad \alpha _{k}:={\frac {\mathbf {r} _{k}^{\mathsf {T}}\mathbf {r} _{k}}{\mathbf {p} _{k}^{\mathsf {T}}\mathbf {Ap} _{k}}}\\&\qquad \mathbf {x} _{k+1}:=\mathbf {x} _{k}+\alpha _{k}\mathbf {p} _{k}\\&\qquad \mathbf {r} _{k+1}:=\mathbf {r} _{k}-\alpha _{k}\mathbf {Ap} _{k}\\&\qquad {\hbox{if }}\mathbf {r} _{k+1}{\text{ is sufficiently small, then exit loop}}\\&\qquad \beta _{k}:={\frac {\mathbf {r} _{k+1}^{\mathsf {T}}\mathbf {r} _{k+1}}{\mathbf {r} _{k}^{\mathsf {T}}\mathbf {r} _{k}}}\\&\qquad \mathbf {p} _{k+1}:=\mathbf {r} _{k+1}+\beta _{k}\mathbf {p} _{k}\\&\qquad k:=k+1\\&{\text{end repeat}}\\&{\text{return }}\mathbf {x} _{k+1}{\text{ as the result}}\end{aligned}
Let's call this algorithm the original Conjugate gradient algorithm.
Now imagine we would alter the algorithm by flipping the minus sign in first step of the algorithm like so: $\mathbf{r}_0 := \mathbf{b} +\mathbf {Ax} _{0}$. Let's call this algorithm the altered Conjugate gradient algorithm.
After applying the original algorithm on the linear system $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, the algorithm converges to the solution $\mathbf x_{og}$. Applying the altered algorithm to the same linear system produces the result $\mathbf x_{al}$.
Can the linear system $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ be transformed into another linear system $\mathbf{\bar A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{\bar b}$ for which the original Conjugate gradient algorithm converges to $\mathbf x_{al}$?
For the sake of simplicity, assume that the linear system is in the form of normal equations of a least squares problem: $\mathbf J^T \mathbf J\mathbf x = -\mathbf J^T \mathbf r$

Edit:
Below is a graph that shows the steps taken by:

the original CG algorithm while solving $\mathbf A \mathbf x_{og} = \mathbf b$ (the green trajectory)
the original CG algorithm while solving $\mathbf A \mathbf x_{su} = \mathbf {-b}$ (the blue trajectory)
the altered CG algorithm while solving $\mathbf A \mathbf x_{al} = \mathbf b$ (the red trajectory)

The Python script which generated the graph, is listed below. Here is a link to a website which lets you run that script for convenience.

The Python script, which was used to generate the graph (it generates a random least-squares equations in each run):
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def cg(A, b, init_x, max_num_iterations, use_altered_variant):
    """
    :param A: The NxN, positive-definite matrix of the linear system Ax = b
    :param b: The right-hand-side vector of the linear system Ax = b
    :param init_x: The initial
    :param max_num_iterations: The PCG iterates either until convergence or until it reaches max_num_iterations
    :param use_altered_variant: Choose whether to use "r = b - Ax" (when use_altered_variant=False) or "r = b + Ax" (when use_altered_variant=True)

    :return: An array of intermediate iteration steps `x`.
    """

    eps = 1e-6
    x = init_x.copy()

    solution_steps = [x.copy()]

    r = None
    if use_altered_variant:
        r = b + A @ x
    else:
        r = b - A @ x

    if np.linalg.norm(r) < eps:
        return np.array(solution_steps)

    p = r.copy()

    for iter_idx in range(max_num_iterations):
        alpha = r.dot(r) / p.dot(A @ p)
        x = x + alpha * p

        solution_steps.append(x.copy())

        old_r_dot_r = r.dot(r)
        r = r - alpha * A @ p

        if np.linalg.norm(r) < eps:
            return np.array(solution_steps)

        beta = r.dot(r) / old_r_dot_r
        p = r + beta * p

    return np.array(solution_steps)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_residuals = 50
    system_size = 2
    num_pcg_iters = 10

    # Initialize the Jacobian matrix and the residual vector of a least squares problem to random values
    J = np.random.rand(num_residuals, system_size) - np.random.rand(2)
    r = np.random.rand(num_residuals) - 0.5

    # Construct the normal equations and choose a random initial guess for the solution
    A = J.T @ J
    b = -J.T @ r
    x_init = np.random.rand(system_size)

    # Run the algorithms
    x_og_steps = cg(A, b, x_init, num_pcg_iters, use_altered_variant=False)  # Solution of the original linear system using the original CG
    x_al_steps = cg(A, b, x_init, num_pcg_iters, use_altered_variant=True)  # Solution of the original linear system using the altered CG
    x_su_steps = cg(A, -b, x_init, num_pcg_iters, use_altered_variant=False)  # Solution of the altered linear system using the original CG

    # Compare the solutions
    print('x_og = ', x_og_steps[-1], ', num steps: ', x_og_steps.shape[0] - 1)
    print('x_al = ', x_al_steps[-1], ', num steps: ', x_al_steps.shape[0] - 1)
    print('x_su = ', x_su_steps[-1], ', num steps: ', x_su_steps.shape[0] - 1)

    # Plot the steps of each algorithm
    plt.plot(x_og_steps[:, 0], x_og_steps[:, 1], '--bo', color='green', label='x_og')
    plt.plot(x_al_steps[:, 0], x_al_steps[:, 1], '--bo', color='red', label='x_al')
    plt.plot(x_su_steps[:, 0], x_su_steps[:, 1], '--bo', color='blue', label='x_su')
    plt.plot(x_init[0], x_init[1], '*', color='black', label='x_init', markersize=15)

    plt.legend(loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05), fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5)
    plt.axis('square')
    plt.plot()
    plt.show()


I bet it's as simple as "Replace $b$ with $-b$."  I.e., the altered system solves $Ax = -b$.

@EricTowers Thank you for your answer. I doesn't seem like solving $Ax = b$ with the altered algorithm is the same as solving $Ax = -b$ with the original algorithm. Please see the edit I made. (Or there might a bug in the code.)
